# Loop through var in object in entity framework

Tags: entity

This is the error I am getting “**foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because object does**”

In DAL I have a function like below, this function is returning an object type items.

```
public static object GetProfileByUserId(Guid userId)

    {
        using (CCSDBEntities objDbContext = new CCSDBEntities())
        {
            var tb = (from p in objDbContext.Membershipstb
                      join addr in objDbContext.AddressTBs on p.UserId equals addr.UserId
                      where p.UserId == userId && addr.AddressType == "Billing"
                      select new
                      {
                          p.UserId,
                          p.Email,
                          addr.ADDID,
                          addr.AddressType,
                          addr.Mobile,
                          addr.CompanyName,
                          addr.AddressLine1,
                          addr.AddressLine2,
                          addr.City,
                          addr.State,
                          addr.Country,
                          addr.PostalCode
                      }).ToList();
            return tb;
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to loop through with object, but it is showing an error like “foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because object does”. I don’t want to create any additional properties. I just want to consume object type items at my UI and display them in textboxes.

```
private void BindProfile(Guid userid)

    {
        var tb = ccsdal.GetProfileByUserId(userid);        
        if (tb != null)
        {
            foreach (var x in tb)
            {
                //    Email.Text = x.Email.Trim();
                //    phone.Text = x.Mobile;
            }

        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to operate with anonymous type in the out of visibility scope. To fix this issue you need to create some kind of model class e.g. `BillingAddress` with all needed properties.

Change definition of `GetProfileByUserId(Guid userId)` to

> public static List<BillingAddress> GetProfileByUserId(Guid userId)

and return the initialized list of this type not the anonymous type.
Consume resulted list on your foreach and perform all needed operations.